# How to read xls file return by Content-Disposition: attachment with PHP

Tags: php, curl, content-disposition

When I access a link, eg: https://demo.com/report?transType=xls it will return a xls to I download. It's response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 19:18:37 GMT
Server: IIS/4.0 (Windows XP)
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*="utf-8''demo.xls
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Length: 14848
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=1000
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Content-Type: text/html

How can I download this file to my server use PHP (CURL, Socket...)? I tried CURL but it don't work. The saved file cannot read :( It's my code:

```
$op = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($op, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://demo.com/report?transType=xls');
curl_setopt ($op, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($op, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($op, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($op, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($op, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($op, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($op, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($op); 
@file_put_contents('saved.xls', $response);
```

Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

To download a file using curl in php you have to use code which is like so:

```
<?php
//File to save the contents to
$fp = fopen ('theFile.xls', 'w+'); 
$url = "https://demo.com/report?transType=xls";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
//give curl the file pointer so that it can write to it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);//get curl response
//done
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```